# Having problems with the method: prepareForReuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, and when it's selected, it expands and adds a `UILabel` to the selected cells `UIView` that I added in the storyBoard.

When I run the app and select a cell, the label gets added to `myView` as expected. The problem is, when I scroll down, the label is also shown at another cell.

Apparently the reason its behaving like so, is because I'm reusing the cell and I don't clean them as Emilie stated. I'm trying to call the method of `prepareForReuse` and 'cleaning' the cell, but I'm having trouble doing that. Here is my code:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
    for (UILablel *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**Doing that, cleans even the selected cells label.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.sortedDictionary = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Californa", @"Alabama", @"Chicago", @"Texas", @"Colorado", @"New York", @"Philly", @"Utah", @"Nevadah", @"Oregon", @"Pensilvainia", @"South Dekoda", @"North Dekoda", @"Iowa", @"Misouri", @"New Mexico", @"Arizona", @"etc", nil];

    self.rowSelection = -1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CategorieCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    customCell.title.text = [self.sortedDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return customCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    CategorieCell *customCell = (CategorieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.info) {
        [self.info removeFromSuperview];
    }

    self.info = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.info setText:@"Hello"];
    [self.info setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];

    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);
    [self.info setFrame:labelFrame];

    [customCell.infoView addSubview:self.info];

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);

    self.rowSelection = [indexPath row];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath row] == self.rowSelection) {
        return 159;
    }
    return 59;
}
```

Comment: It's not prepareForReuse, it's that you create an instance of mainVC, check a pointer in that instance, then "remove" a subview using a pointer from that object, even though the object is newly created and empty, and even though you should be using a value from the cell (of which there are many for each table view).  This reveals that you have no concept of what an "object" is.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism, but I'm still not sure what to do. I understand where I went wrong, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: When I 'clean' the labels from the view, they all disappear, Is there a way to keep the selected rows label?

Comment: If you want to keep track of which cell is selected, even after it scrolls off the screen, you need to do that in your dataSource structure.  The TableView is only a "window" into your dataSource, and the dataSource should contain all the (non-UI) info that the cells do.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please?

Comment: You have a dataSource -- some sort of table that is consulted by `cellForRow...`.  In that table you need to keep track of selected cells.

Comment: Then how can I access it from the customCell.m?

Comment: I can' do this: MainVC *main = [[MainVC alloc] init]; cuz then it creates a new MainVC and what ever variables I try accessing, it will give me nil, or 0.

Comment: You're right about that.  But when you first "see" a cell you're in `cellForRow...` inside the dataSource.  You can easily store a pointer to the dataSource in the cell at that time.

Comment: Don't really understand. Can you provide some sample code please?

Comment: No.  You get into trouble just copying code.  Figure it out.  What class is `cellForRow...` in?  What token do you use to refer to the object that you're currently executing in?  You presumably have your own CategorieCell class (which hopefully you've "registered" with the TableView) that you can add, eg, a pointer field to.

Comment: I tried putting: mainVC *main = (mainVC *)main.rowSelection; in the prepareForReuse method, but it gave me an error.

Comment: main is where all the code for the tableview is at. The error sais "Cast of NSInteger (aka 'long') to "mainVC" is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: I doubt it.  `main` isn't in the picture here, unless your code is really weird.  You have a class (`@interface` &  `@implementation`) that contains the logic of your table view, most likely including the implementations of the UITableViewDataSource protocol methods.  When you're in that class it calls the instance of itself `self`.

Comment: my `main` class is where cellForRowAtIndexPath is and the number of rows in section, etc.

Comment: You have a class called "main"?  (That's not a good idea.)  But even if that is the name of the class, that's not how you refer to the current object instance.  You use `self`.

Comment: In `customCell.m`, in the method of `prepareForReuse`, I inserted the following line of code:`mainVC *main = (mainVC *)main.rowSelection`.

Comment: But you give me no idea what `main` is, or what `rowSelection` is.  Show me the declaration of `main`.

Comment: main is a new declaration. mainVC.m is the class with all the logic of the table view

Comment: I'm talking to a wall!!  Sorry, I'm all done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple : you reuse your cell like you should, but never clean them

Reusing your `UITableViewCell` means that the cell you clicked on previously will be reused when it will go off-screen.

When clicked, you add a view to your `UITableViewCell`. When reused, the view is still there because you never remove it.

You have two choices : One, you could set a tag of the self.info view (or check with the indexpath you're keeping in memory), then check when you dequeue the cell if the info view is there, and remove it. The cleaner solution would be to implement the view removal by overriding the `prepareForReuse` method of your custom `UITableViewCell`

**Precision**

The first thing you need to do is set a tag for your self.info view after initializing it:

```
[self.info setTag:2222];
```

If you want to keep it as simple as possible, you could check and remove the self.info view directly in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method :

```
CategorieCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
customCell.title.text = [self.sortedDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if [customCell.infoView viewWithTag: 2222] != nil {
    [self.info removeFromSuperview]
} 
return customCell;
```

I am not a percent sure this code compiles, I cannot test it on my side for now. Hope it works !

Comment: When I 'clean' the labels from the view, they all disappear, Is there a way to keep the selected rows label?

Comment: I added a little precision